# GeoDjango + Postgis missing functions

Tags: django, postgresql, postgis, geodjango

So I've been using a Postgres database with the extension Postgis installed, and then using a Django setup to draw spatial data on a Leaflet OpenStreetMap. It has been a bit difficult translating my sql queries to the database functionality that Django is using whenever you're communicating with your database. Often I seem to be missing Postgis functions such as ST_LineCrossingDirection or ST_FrechetDistance.
How do I get to use those functions along with .annotate and .filter from Django without having to write custom sql queries and executing those?
I've tried to look into F() and Func() from Django as well, but I don't think that solves my issue as it seem to be using built in aggregate functions. I also tried to execute RawSQL in an annotate function to perform the function ST_LineCrossingDirection but it would require me to write a WHERE clause and the condition is something I'm not aware of until I get to the filter() call where I'm using intersects() between two geometries.
Anyway .. If anyone knows how to use what I assume is missing Postgis functions please let me know. Because my code is getting quite messy and ineffective.

Thanks, and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [GeoFunc](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/gis/db/models/functions.py#L88), it's the GeoDjango equivalent of Django's Func.

```py
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import GeoFunc

class LineCrossingDirection(GeoFunc):
    function='ST_LineCrossingDirection'

class FrechetDistance(GeoFunc):
    function='ST_FrechetDistance'
```